# How can I access the last help popup?

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm new to IntelliJ and sometimes there appear popups in the top right corner giving some advice or suggestion about features I could use. I just saw one advice and wanted to read more on it but then it closed. Is there a way to see a log or history of previous advices?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The editor [Event Log](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/event-log.html) should hold all the messages that have appeared in popups since you opened any particular project

The even log can either be accessed either by going to View -> Tool Windows -> Event Log or clicking the link at the bottom of the editor: [image: Event Log]